# Load testing a Google App Engine Application using JMeter

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, jmeter

I've created an application and I'd like to test how well it scales to large numbers of users.

To run my application a user has to go to the homepage, sign in to a Google account, click a button and then upload a video file.

First of all, is this possible to emulate using JMeter? I'm signed into my Google account locally but am not sure whether simulated users will have access to it?

Secondly, I've recorded a session in JMeter doing the actions above and have run the test with 10 simulated users, however, the App Engine dashboard doesn't detect any activity. I've followed the steps mentioned [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) but obviously with details of my application etc.

Here's a screenshot of the summary report.
[image: JMeter Screenshot]

Is there anything obvious I might be doing wrong? Am I using JMeter in the correct way to test the application as desired?

Apologies for my JMeter inexperience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you will be able to record and replay, my expectation is that your application is protected by [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) so you will need some `token` in order to execute your calls.

Not knowing the details of your application implementation it's quite hard to guess what's went wrong, I would recommend

1. Running your test with 1 user and 1 loop first to ensure that it's doing what it is supposed to be doing by adding [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspecting request and response details for each sampler (especially for failed ones).
2. Once you figure out what's wrong with this particular request - amend JMeter configuration so it would be successful. Repeat until you're happy with the test end-to-end.
3. Add load only after that and be careful as test might be sensitive to extra users/loops, especially if you're using a single login account (which is not recommended)

References:

- [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)
- [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)